# go: updates to go.mod needed; to update it:

Tags: go

When I try to run the tests: go test...
I get an error:

```
$ go test ...
go: updates to go.mod needed; to update it:
```

```
go mod tidy
```

I'm launching

```
$ go mod tidy
```

And again I get an error:

```
$ go test ...
```

```
go: updates to go.mod needed; to update it:
go mod tidy
```

Help
https://github.com/kam1sh/overprocessed/
Thanks

Comment: Use `./...` to run all tests. Not sure what the `...` is doing though.

Answer (score 2):

When I tested it, I was required to use Go 1.18+ and the proper parameter for tests, `go test ./...`, as pointed out by @s3vt. The latter allows the test runner to recursively dive into subdirectories to find test files to run.

Comment: Where to read about ./...? thanks